# Entity Framework Core: foreign key and reference table Id column do not match

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using EF Core 5 for developing. I have an existing database, so changing columns may not be a good option.

For example I got two tables:

```
public class CalssA
{
    public long AId { get; set; }
    public long TheBId { get; set; }
    [Foreign("TheBId")]
    public virtual ClassB B { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public long BId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(CalssA.B))]
    public virtual ICollection<ClassA> Aas {get;set;}
}
```

When I try to get A data with B, it seems B info is not join to the A.

```
var a = _AContext.As.Include(a => a.B).FirstOrDefault();
var b = a.B // get null
```

Is it join issue? How should I specify the column to join with EF Core?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add navigation properties

```
public class ClassA
{  
    [Key]
    public long AId { get; set; }

    public long? TheBId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey( nameOf(TheBId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameOf(ClassB.Aas))] 
    public virtual ClassB B { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
    [Key]
    public long BId { get; set; }
    
  
      [InverseProperty(nameof(ClassA.B))]
    public virtual ICollection<ClassA>  Aas {get; set;} //one-to-many
}
```

you can try to add to dbcontext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.B)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Aas)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.TheBId);
                  
            });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried your way, but the property B is still null.
I use `[InverseProperty(nameof(A.B))] public virtual ICollection<A>  Aas {get; set;}` and `[InverseProperty("Aas")]`

Comment: @jamesaq12wsx It should be working., since it is a  simple basic configuration. I am afraid you will have to delete migration folder and  migration table of db. After this you will have repeat  initial migration to DB and only after this try again

Comment: Hi @Serge, I didn't use migration function of ef core this time cause the database is already exist.

Comment: Can you check then if  TheBId  is a foreign key of B table of database.

Comment: No it isn't. I change the `[ForeignKey('TheBId')]` to `[ForeignKey("Id")]` and it works

Comment: What is the name of  column    of TheBId  propery?

Comment: I modify the question to show more realistic of my table naming and.
Its "TheBId" in table A, and in table B its "BId".

Comment: @jamesaq12wsx Everything looks ok,  you only forgot to add [InverseProperty(nameOf(ClassB.Aas))] to ClassA

Comment: Thank you, 
Just confirm in ClassA should I put 
    `[ForeignKey( nameOf(TheBId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameOf(ClassB.Aas))] 
    public virtual ClassB B { get; set; }` 
or `[ForeignKey( nameOf(BId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameOf(ClassB.Aas))] 
    public virtual ClassB B { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, everything should be the same as it is in my answer now. Only [ForeignKey( nameOf(BId))]  is not correct.  Should be [ForeignKey( nameOf(TheBId))]